# XCode 8 - Build works but archive fails - React Native

Tags: xcode, xcode8, react-native-ios

I have an haunting issue. I am trying to build an React Native app in Xcode 8. Build/Run in Simulator works fine but as soon I start to archive I am getting the following error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

That's the only error and it's after all steps have been completed with no further explanation.

Now I installed Fastlane and found out that it fails because of duplicate symbols. Removing the duplicates from "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" solves the issue and allows me to archive the app.

However now I can't build anymore for the simulator because of missing symbols.

I been looking into this for 2 days now and I can't find a solution.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for it!

Based on this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12814 if you use Pods, it also includes the base react project which will end up causing the duplicate references.

In order to fix this issue, the react reference need to be removed:

1. Open your [yourproject].xcworkspace
2. Select your Pods project
3. In TARGETS delete React. (clicking on the minus button - below of the targets list.)
4. Clean (Product > Clean) & archive/build/whatever.

Kudos to andfk for this solution!